# Компиляция пользовательских методов

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Можно ли скомпилировать пользовательский метод (пусть даже класс) из string, и использовать его в своей программе? По теме гуглил. Находил только примеры компиляции сразу в exe/dll, а хотелось бы в память, для последующего использования. В asp.net это как то реализовано...

Comment: Гуглили [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)?

Comment: Смотрел, конечно. Это не то.

Comment: Вам же надо строку скомпилировать, так? Разве [это](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis) или [это](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn) не то, что вам надо?

Comment: Да, этим можно пользоваться. Но, это всё слишком громоздко и ресурсоёмко. Стандартная библиотека .net уже умеет что надо из коробки - нужно только правильно воспользоваться. А так то проще будет dll во временный каталог компилить, чем такую громадину, как Roslyn, тащить в проект.

Comment: Нуу, я уж точно не знаю, что вам нужно. Может вам вообще [Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx) подойдет или [вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/172487/) занятная статейка.

Comment: @VladD Почему вопрос отмечен как дубликат вопроса с ответом про Roslyn, если автор четко написал, что Roslyn ему не подходит?

Comment: По той ссылке оказалось и то, что нужно. Без Roslyn, штатными средствами.

Comment: Принял, вопросов нет :)